# Chapter title leading

Tags: sectioning, chapters, line-spacing

I have a strange problem in my Chapter title as in figure:

[image]

How can I set the correct leading between the two last lines in the title?

Comment: Which document class do you use? have you used special commands to formate your chapter title? A [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) would be very helpful ... BTW: Welcome to TeX.SX! You may have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436).

Comment: although it's definitely desirable to know what document class you're using, if you put `{\strut}` between the two words on the second line, that will add "virtual" descenders to that line, which in turn will keep the lines spread apart evenly.  i suspect that this title is being set while a smaller font is in effect, and is not ended by a paragraph break, which is necessary to "freeze" the baseline spacing for the larger font.  if that's the case, then putting `\endgraf` at the end should also fix the bad spacing.

Comment: I suspect barbara's comment is in the right direction, but without a MWE can't be sure: for me that makes the question unclear.